# unable to fetch data from app engine datastore(using JDO Queries)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, jdoql

I am trying to fetch data from app engine with no success. The Async call is a success but there are no data printed. There are no errors either. It worked fine when I was using backend database. Now I am trying to get the same project to work with app engine datastore. I am using JDO queries. Below is the 'get' method:

```
public Projects getProjects(String projectname) throws NotFoundException,
        NotLoggedInException {
    checkLoggedIn();
    PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
    Projects proj = null;
    try{
        Query q = pm.newQuery(Projects.class);
            q.setFilter("projectname == projname" );
            q.declareParameters("String projname");
        List<Projects> result = (List<Projects>) q.execute(projectname);
        for(Projects et : result){
            proj = new Projects(et.getPID(), et.getProjectName());
        }
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return proj;
}
```

I am not sure where it is going wrong. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The source code looks fine, so there may be something wrong with the data or the JDO configuration.

Comment: Martin Thanks. Somehow it is working now, It is getting the project name and ID, though I did not make any changes!

Comment: I would log the cause of the error as "Pointy haired boss was signed in for a long time when it happened".  True, no?